# PHP Soap Call Giving me Errors

Tags: php, web-services, api, soap

Hi I'm trying to setup an api service with Limoanywhere system. But regardless of what I do I get invalid ApiKey & ApiID. I went into the back system and changed the ApiKey & ApiId multiple times but still no success.

Can anyone tell me if my code is correct?

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('https://qa.book.mylimobiz.com/api/ApiService.asmx?wsdl');
$options = array(
                'ApiKey' => '***api key here****',
                'ApiID'  => '***api id here****'
                );
$result = $client->__soapCall('Test', $options);
//var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
print_r($result);
?>
```

**Here is the snippet from the service**

http://qa.book.mylimobiz.com/api/ApiService.asmx?op=Test

**Here is the result I get from when run my php code.**

```
Array ( [TestResult] => Array ( [ResponseCode] => 1 [ResponseText] => Invalid ApiId or ApiKey ) )
```

Comment: I guess it should be `$result = $client->Test($options);` Can you try that?

Comment: @hek2mgl tried that similar error

    stdClass Object ( [TestResult] => stdClass Object ( [ResponseCode] => 1 [ResponseText] => Invalid ApiId or ApiKey ) )

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure about this. Should had a look into the documentation. But that's why it was just a comment ....

Answer (score 0):

Check this instead of test Test function not working giving error but test of the test all function are working.

```
<?php
        $soapClient = new SoapClient("https://book.mylimobiz.com/api/ApiService.asmx?wsdl");

        // Prepare SoapHeader parameters
        $sh_param = array('apiId'    =>    'xxxxxx','apiKey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');

        $headers = new SoapHeader('https://book.mylimobiz.com/api/ApiService.asmx?wsdl', 'GetVehicleTypes', $sh_param);

        // Prepare Soap Client
        $trans = $soapClient->GetVehicleTypes($sh_param)->GetVehicleTypesResult;

        echo "<pre>"; print_r($trans);

?>
```